# How can I find highest and lowest in an array of objects/ Javascript

Tags: javascript, arrays, object, average

I am new in js, can u help me finding the highest and lowest temperature in array of objects

```
let weather = [
  { month: 'March',   temperature: [2,5,4,3,7,12]},
  { month: 'April', temperature: [14,15,16,19, 20]},
  { month: 'May',   temperature: [22,24,26,28,27]}
]
```

Comment: This feels like a homework question, so I expect no one will give you the answers directly, and will instead help you find them yourself. Your inner loop is using `weather.length` which is likely not doing what you expect given the number of temperature values for each month is different to the number of months. Once you've got the correct average for each month, you would then need to find the minimum of those averages, and the maximum of those averages. How can you do that?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've mutated the object and added `lowest`, 'highest', and 'average' in the object itself.

To get the `month` and `temperature`, I've used [object destructuring](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Destructuring_assignment).

Then sort the array using `sort` function.

Now the tempArray is sorted and the element at index `0` is the `lowest` and the element at `temporary.length - 1` is the `highest element.

To get average of an array, I've used the array [reduce](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/Reduce) function.

```js
let weather = [
  { month: "March", temperature: [2, 5, 4, 3, 7, 12] },
  { month: "April", temperature: [14, 15, 16, 19, 20] },
  { month: "May", temperature: [22, 24, 26, 28, 27] },
];

let getAverage = (array) => array.reduce((a, b) => a + b) / array.length;

weather.forEach((monthData) => {
  const { month, temperature } = monthData;
  
  // temporary sorted array
  const tempArray = [...temperature].sort((a, b) => a - b);
  
  // Lowest
  monthData.lowest = tempArray[0];
  
  // Heighest
  monthData.highest = tempArray[tempArray.length - 1];
  
  // Average
  monthData.average = getAverage(tempArray);
});

console.log(weather);

const averageArray = weather
  .map((month) => month.average)
  .sort((a, b) => a - b);

const lowestInAverage = averageArray[0];
const highestInAverage = averageArray[averageArray.length - 1];

console.log(lowestInAverage, highestInAverage);
```

Comment: Thanks a lot, but the question is to get and analyse the highest and lowest among months in average. Like the hottest and the coldest month. How can I get it? Should I use for in?

Comment: @RoyFied updated code, Lowest and highest among months in average. Is this what you've asked

Comment: Exactly! Thank you very much! U helped me a lot

Answer (score 0):

Use map & reduce. Inside map callback use Math.max & Math.min to find highest and lowest temperature and use sort to sort the array by ascending order of average temperature

```js
let weather = [{
    month: 'March',
    temperature: [2, 5, 4, 3, 7, 12]
  },
  {
    month: 'April',
    temperature: [14, 15, 16, 19, 20]
  },
  {
    month: 'May',
    temperature: [22, 24, 26, 28, 27]
  }
]

const val = weather.map(item => {
  return {
    month: item.month,
    temperature: item.temperature,
    lowest: Math.min(...item.temperature),
    highest: Math.max(...item.temperature),
    avgTemp: item.temperature.reduce((acc, curr) => {
      return (acc + curr)
    }, 0) / item.temperature.length
  }
}).sort((a, b) => a.avgTemp - b.avgTemp)
console.log(val)
```